# R: regexp \\s is not empty space

Tags: r, regex

I'm just wondering why `\\s`does not work  bracket `[]` for options but empty space does work. Here is an example:

```
sub("[a-z ]+[a-z]+","it works","abcd xyz")
# [1] "it works
```

This is what I want. But if I use `\\s` I got this:

```
sub("[a-z\\s]+[a-z]+","it works","abcd xyz")
# [1] "it works xyz"
```

And also [[:space:]] does not gives the result I want:

```
sub("[a-z[[:space:]]]+[a-z]+","it works","abcd xyz") 
# [1] "abcd xyz"
```

Why does `\\s` not work within option brackets?

This concerns programming language R.

Comment: It is not `[[:space:]]`, since you already have the outer `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if we specify `perl = TRUE`.  By default it is `FALSE`

```
sub("[a-z\\s]+[a-z]+","it works","abcd xyz", perl = TRUE)
#[1] "it works"
```

Comment: OK. I understand: I have to use Perl Syntax. Thanks a lot for this answer.

Comment: Just for curiousity: what is the name of the regexp-syntax by default for grep/sub (that is when perl = FALSE)?

Comment: @giordano  If you check `?regex` `Two types of regular expressions are used in R, extended regular expressions (the default) and Perl-like regular expressions used by perl = TRUE.`

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in the comment, you have *three* square brackets in your last regex, only two are necessary.
Any of the following will do what you want.

```
sub("[a-z[:space:]]+[a-z]+","it works","abcd xyz")
sub("[[:lower:][:space:]]+[[:lower:]]+","it works","abcd xyz")
#[1] "it works"
```